# WebService test from within Weblogic server (12c)

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, datasource, jdeveloper

I have deployed a sample webservice application to remote weblogic server (12C) which has a datasource that accesses a remote database server. 
The deployment  was successful. 
The data source was tested OK from within the Weblogic Server. 
But when I am trying to test the webservice (which uses this datasource) I am getting the following error

1. inside weblogic

[image: Error in weblogic server] ![enter image description here]

2. When I am testing the same webservice from standalone url (webservice test client - see image) I am getting the following error for the same method. The User name and passowrd for base authentication is correct. Though I am not very sure what/why the base authentication is required, since the data-source has it all. Please advise how to test a webservice that is acessing a remote database through a data source. Link to an example using remote weblogic server and remote database server will also be a great help.

   ! [In webservice test client] [image]

[image]